# Register user without password

Tags: registration, password

We're looking for a way to register a user without requiring that they specify a password and instead mail them the password as part of the account verification process.

Is this even remotely possible with EE or a module like Expresso FreeMember?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW Simple Registration has support for disabling passwords in the signup form, auto-generating a password and emailing that password to the user.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/simple-registration

Answer (score 0):

On your form, you could set the password field as "hidden" and give it a value. (Either hardcode in a value or - better yet - have some randomly-generated string as that field value.) Then, as part of the account verification process, they're shown a link to retrieve their "lost" password and reset it.

The downside there is that the password - whether randomly-generated or hardcoded - would be visible in the page source. This could net you a lot of spam signups, which is never fun.

Is there a reason you're doing this? If you're trying to cut down on spam signups, and force a multi-step account verification procedure, couldn't you route everyone into a certain member group, and have all new members perform some minor task (entering some data into a form that's visible only to members in that group, for example) - and then everyone who doesn't perform that task in five days, their membership is either deleted, or they're moved to the Banned members group?

Comment: Hi Leigh, thanks for the suggestion. It reminded me that I coded an extension some time back to send a welcome email with a username/password in plain text to a user following registration through the CP. I could probably leverage this and change the hooks which it fires on. I'll report back and let you know how I get on. :)